# Examples of products of G-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose that $K$ is a $G$-complex and $K'$ is a $G'$-complex. Then $K\times K'$ with the product cell-structure and the weak topology is a ${\bf \mathbf{GxG'}-complex}$

Can someone show me some examples?

I have just started learning about equivariant cohomology theory.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to think about $G$-sets instead of complexes or topological spaces or anything else with more structure? That can be added on without too much additional effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask about examples of $G$-complexes, a nice class arises as follows:
If $V$ is an orthogonal $G$-representation, then its unit sphere has a structure of a finite $G$-complex (A $G$-CW-structure is described in: Lück, Transformation Groups and Algebraic K-theory on page 9, available on the webpage of the author).

For example, the finite cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}/n$ act on $S^1$ and you can imagine a $G$-CW structure by taking $\mathbb{Z}/n$ act on the $n$-gon by rotations.

Now if you take the product of two such $S^1$'s, one with a $\mathbb{Z}/n$-action, the other with a $\mathbb{Z}/m$-action, you get by the process you described a $\mathbb{Z}/n \times \mathbb{Z}/m$-complex structure on the torus which you can even draw.

Another very important example is of course the following: The universal cover of a connected CW-complex $X$ has a structure of a $\pi_1(X)$-CW complex. If $X$ and $Y$ are connected CW-complexes, their product has fundamental group isomorphic to $\pi_1(X)\times \pi_1(Y)$ and its universal cover is homeomorphic to the universal covers $\widetilde{X}, \widetilde{Y}$ of $X$ resp. $Y$. On this, there is a $\pi_1(X\times Y) = \pi_1(X)\times \pi_1(Y)$-action. Now it can be equipped by a $\pi_1(X)\times \pi_1(Y)$-CW structure by the process you mentioned.

One has to be a little careful with products of $CW$-complexes, when not working in compactly generated weak hausdorff spaces.

Comment: Thank you it makes so much more sense now.